# Setblock clock with scoreboard doesn't work in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying some things with scoreboard lately and I always get to the point where I need to use the following commands.

```
/scoreboard players set @a Holding 0
/scoreboard players set @a Holding 1 {DataTag}
/execute @e[score_Holding_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon LightningBolt ~ ~ ~
```

People tell me to connect these to the same setblock clock but in order. I do that this way.

[image]

But nothing happens. The problem seems that the Holding score is set back to 0 too fast for the execute command to work. Does anyone know how to make this setup work?

Comment: Maybe set *Holding* to 0 **after** the `/execute`? Just an idea to reset after executing.

Comment: Tried it, No result. It seems that, wherever the Holding 0 is placed in the setup, it always errors.

Comment: I see you are using the 1.9 snapshot. Are you comfortable with using chain command blocks to get this working?

Comment: No, and how are you seeing I'm using 1.9?

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here and proclaim that the execute command is at a lower X or Z coordinate than the other two blocks, making your commands run backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command blocks are placed in the wrong order in the world.

When multiple command blocks are powered at the same time, they are executed in the direction of +X, +Y and +Z. It is very likely that your line of redstone "points" in the -X or -Z direction, thus making the game run the commands in reverse order:

```
/execute @e[score_Holding_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon LightningBolt ~ ~ ~
/scoreboard players set @a Holding 1 {DataTag}
/scoreboard players set @a Holding 0
```

This leaves every players Holding score at 0 at when the `execute` command is run, therefore it does not execute properly.

---

In 1.9+, chain command blocks should be used to easily prevent such issues.

Comment: Actually, it's more likely that the blocks are just activated [in random order](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/235449/1351).

Answer (score 0):

I have already found a solution myself. This is the working setup:

[image]

Take note that the *Holding 0* block is at the end and that no redstone is on top of it. This worked for me. After reading some comments, it seems that the location of the redstone blocks was the problem. The order in which the commands are executed goes from low to high, so from a low X to a higher X. The same goes for the Y and Z coordinates.

Comment: Personally i suggest a fill clock, not a setblock redstone clock. The fill clock is more reliable than this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2M5n1oIbmQ

Comment: Also check the direction the command blocks are, the commands are executed in the direction of +X, +Y, and +Z, they may be running in the inverse order.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Here, the command blocks are in correct XYZ but in my original setup, they aren't. You might have saved my day.

Comment: These little things that aren't that hard to solve but can ruin your day is one of the perks of minecraft. Got screwed over more than once by this particular one.