# InGround tag for tridents?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Link I'll be referencing to: [Specific lightning arrow task, after the arrow strikes, and only using a specific bow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/391637/specific-lightning-arrow-task-after-the-arrow-strikes-and-only-using-a-specifi)

This is just a quick question, using the chain of commands in circusbaby23's answer, is it possible to replace all arrow references with a trident?

Things that will change (Highlighted with **):

```
/scoreboard objectives add **UseTrident** **minecraft.used:trident
```

```
execute at @a[scores={**UseTrident**=1..},nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"**minecraft:trident**",Count:1b,tag:{**Name of trident in here**}}}] run data merge entity @e[type=trident,limit=1,sort=nearest,distance=..2] {Tags:["**lightningtrident**"]}
```

```
execute as @a[scores={UseBow=1..}] at @e[type=**trident**,tag=**lightningtrident**,nbt={inGround:1b},limit=1] run summon minecraft:lightning_bolt
```

etc.

Will it work?

Comment: There is no need to confirm your commands with experts before implementing them. You'll be able to get your task done much more quickly by [trying it out](https://tryitands.ee) first and reporting back only if it doesn't work.

Comment: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Trident#Data_values - yes, it will work

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Thanks, maybe someone can close this now.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 The reason I'm asking but not trying is because I'm only allowed on MC on Fridays and Saturdays. I want to see if anyone answers before my designated MC time :)